# VB.NET OleDbDataAdapter Fill Function is creating duplicate "Columns"

Tags: vb.net, datatable, clone, fill, oledbdataadapter

I am working with two DataTables. I am using the Clone() function on the first DataTable which is returned from SQL. The Clone() function is used to create an identical schema for my second DataTable. I am using the OleDbDataAdapter Fill() function to populate the second DataTable with data from a CSV file. After calling the Clone() function, I do see that it created the correct number of columns (88). After calling the Fill() function on the second DataTable, I inspected the column count which has now doubled to 176. Inspecting the 1st row, the first 88 items in the ItemArray are "" and items 89-176 are populated correctly from the CSV. There should only be 88 columns, period. Any ideas what may be causing the duplication columns after calling the Fill() function? Thanks!

Comment: If you use `Fill` the columns are also created. So it's pointless to  create the table via `Clone` first. MSDN: _"f the DbDataAdapter encounters duplicate columns while populating a DataTable, it generates names for the subsequent columns, using the pattern "columnname1", "columnname2", "columnname3", and so on."_

Comment: This makes sense and answers my duplicate problem. Thank you. I do need to call the Clone() function on the first DataTable because I need it's schema before populating the 2nd DataTable with the CSV data. The two DataTables having matching schema, different data, will come into play later.